# Find words in multiple files and sort in another

Tags: bash, for-loop, printf

Need help with "`printf`" and "`for`" loop.

I have individual files each named after a user `(e.g. john.txt, david.txt)` and contains various commands that each user ran. Example of commands are `(SUCCESS, TERMINATED, FAIL, etc.)`. Files have multiple lines with various text but each line contains one of the commands (1 command per line).

Sample:

```
  command: sendevent "-F" "SUCCESS" "-J" "xxx-ddddddddddddd"
  command: sendevent "-F" "TERMINATED" "-J" "xxxxxxxxxxx-dddddddddddddd"
```

I need to go through each file, count the number of each command and put it in another output file in this format:

```
==== John ====
SUCCESS - 3
TERMINATED - 2
FAIL - 4

TOTAL 9


==== David ====
SUCCESS - 1
TERMINATED - 1
FAIL - 2

TOTAL 4
```

Comment: Not much clear, how the files looks like, please put samples of the files too in your post.

Comment: Files have multiple lines with various text but each line contains one of the commands (1 command per line)

Comment: Add content of john.txt to your question.

Comment: Added a sample of a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

P.S. This code can be made more compact, e.g there is no need to use so many echo's etc, but the following structure is being used to make it clear what's happening:

```
ls | grep .txt | sed 's/.txt//' > names


for s in $(cat names)
do
suc=$(grep "SUCCESS" "$s.txt" | wc -l)
termi=$(grep "TERMINATED" "$s.txt"|wc -l)
fail=$(grep "FAIL" "$s.txt"|wc -l)
echo "===  $s  ===" >>docs
echo "SUCCESS  -  $suc" >> docs
echo "TERMINATED  -  $termi" >> docs
echo "FAIL  -  $fail" >> docs
echo "TOTAL $(($termi+$fail+$suc))">>docs
done
```

Output from my test files was like :

```
===new===
SUCCESS  -  0
TERMINATED  -  0
FAIL  -  0
TOTAL 0
===vv===
SUCCESS  -  0
TERMINATED  -  0
FAIL  -  0
TOTAL 0
```

based on [karafka's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1435869/karakfa) suggestions instead of using the above lines for the **for-loop**you can directly use the following:

```
for f in *.txt 
do 
something 
#in order to print the required name in the file without the .txt you can do a
printf "%s\n" ${f::(-4)}
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem is I don't have `-P` or `-o` option on this machine: 
grep: illegal option -- P
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .
5.10 Generic_150400-48 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V490

Comment: @PFD okay made the edits in accordance with the permissions you have :)

Comment: What I couldn't figure out is how to make it go through file names and your first line is what I was missing `ls | grep .txt | sed 's/.txt//' > names`. I made some changes: `SUCCESS=$(grep -c "SUCCESS" "$s.txt")`, makes the output looks nices. Also instead of `echo` I used `printf` to enclose the entire output. Otherwise this solution makes sense to me! Thank you!

Comment: this is most definitely wrong approach `ls | grep .txt | sed 's/.txt//' > names;  for s in $(cat names)`.  You should use `for f in *.txt` instead.

Comment: Do you mean like this?

`for f in *.txt 
do 
suc=$(grep -c "SUCCESS" "$f.txt")
echo "SUCCESS  -  $suc" >> docs
done`

Comment: yes that will work my printf suggestion is only when you need to store the name. so the printf will remove the last .txt part and save john

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -vOFS=" - " 'function pr() {s=0; 
                                  for(k in a) {s+=a[k]; print k,a[k]}; 
                                  print "\nTOTAL "s"\n\n\n"} 
                 NR!=1 && FNR==1 {pr(); delete a} 
                 FNR==1          {print "==== " FILENAME " ===="} 
                                 {a[$4]++} 
                 END             {pr()}' file1 file2 ...
```

if your input file is not structured (key is not always on fourth field), you can do the same with pattern match.

Comment: `awk` always scares me. How would you run this? What is file1, file2?

Comment: these are the input files to the script "...have individual files each named after a user (e.g. john.txt, david.txt)...", or provide via wildcard i.e. `awk ... *.txt`

Comment: Well, this is an `awk` program not pipe joined unix commands.  Each approach has pros and cons and more appropriate based on specific circumstances.